# name of UIView that was touched

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

How can I get the name of the [touch view] in the touchesbegan event.
So if it were UIView *aaaaaview I would get aaaaaview as the return;
Thank You,
nonono

Comment: I'm curious what you're using this for?

Answer (score 3):

"UIView *aaaaaView" just refers to a place in memory. So if you had

```
UIView *aView;
UIView *anotherView;
aView = anotherView;
```

and the user touched a UIView, would the view's name be "aView" or "anotherView"? In particular, a UIView has no knowledge of the name of the variable you use to store it.

I think you're going to have to initialise an NSDictionary mapping names to UIViews.

Something in your -viewDidLoad like this, perhaps:

```
yourDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          @"aaaaaView", aaaaaView, @"viewTwo", viewTwo, nil];
```

and then in your event you can say

```
NSString *viewName = (NSString *) [yourDictionary objectForKey: [touch view]];
```

Comment: `-initWithObjectsAndKeys:` should be `nil` terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The `touches` parameter is a set of `UITouch` instances, which have a corresponding [`view`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_7) property:

> The value of the property is the view object in which the touch originally occurred.

`UIView`s don't have a specific name, but you can just check for their identity, i.e.:

```
if([touch view] == aaaview) {}
```

or use `- (BOOL)isEqual:`.

You could also use the `tag` property instead to give them meaningful identities:

```
enum MyViews {
    AaaView,
    // ...
};

aaaview.tag = AaaView;

// ...
if([touch view].tag == AaaView) {}
```

If you really need names for some reason not mentioned in the question, you could subclass `UIView` and introduce a name property.

Comment: How do I get the name f the view in which the touch originally occured

Comment: As gf and Frank explain, the view doesn't *have* a name. You can get the name of the class, but the variable name that you use when you code the app doesn't exist in the compiled code. Variable names are just an aid for us while we are programming. If you just want to identify views, the fastest way is to use the tag property, where you can store and read an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe something like this:

```
if ([viewController.nibName isEqualToString:@"aaaaView"])
```