# Objective C: how to get the string equivalent, or variable name of a method argument call

Tags: ios, uiview, frame, nslog

I want to make a simple method that logs a view's frame, but also logs the name of the specific view input. Is there an easy way to get the string equivalent of the called view, aside from inputting a string as an argument to the method?

```
-(void)printViewFrame:(UIView*)view { 

    NSLog(@"%@'s frame is: origin x: %f, origin y: %f, size x: %f, size y: %f", view ,view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height);

}

[self printViewFrame:myView];
```

**NOTE:** for now I am just doing this, which is a little ugly:

```
-(void)printViewFrame:(UIView*)view name:(NSString*)name {

    NSLog(@"%@'s frame: %@",name, NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame));

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'string equivalent'? Can you give an example?

Comment: yes, so in other words the first thing in my log above would read is "myView", followed by the origin x , y and size x, y.

Comment: View Name? what does it mean?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to print the name of a variable passed to the method?

Comment: yup variable. I think so, sorry, should have put it that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the view's frame you can use `NSStringFromCGRect`

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame));
```

But if you want to get the name of the view you will have to pass it through as an NSString. You can only read the memory address of the pointer and not it's real name. The closest you'll get to this is

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([view class]));
```

which will output

> UIView

Comment: Thanks, that prints the name of the method. I'm looking for the variable.

Comment: @Mrwolfy Ohh, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 1):

your method call

```
[self printViewFrame:myView];
```

method implementation

```
-(void)printViewFrame:(UIView*)view { 

    NSLog(@"%@ : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(view.frame),NSStringFromClass(view.class));

}
```

Comment: just looking for the variable name. I can easily do it but I have to input the name as a string. I was wondering if there is a clever way to capture the name.

Comment: I have edit the answer please check that if that would help you

Answer (score 0):

I think the only possible way to implement what you need is to log a variable's name before calling `-(void)printViewFrame:` method

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with some standard function, but i can do this with macro:

```
#define PRINT_NAME(var) NSLog(@"%s", #var)
```

Then, you just call it and it prints variable's name:

```
PRINT_NAME(view);
```

You can also use this to get a `NSString` with needed name:

```
#define GET_NAME_STRING(var) [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", #var]
```

to use it like this:

```
NSLog(@"frame stuff %f,...., NAME IS %@", frame.x, ..., GET_NAME_STRING(view));
```

If you need only one method (or some) you can do some defines to do what you want:

```
#define CALL_PRINT(var) NSLog(@"%s", #var); [self printViewFrame:var]
```

So, when you call

```
CALL_PRINT(myView);
```

It will print the view name and then call the `printViewFrame` function.

Also, if you don't want to do anything with macro found something there: [name of UIView that was touched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750993/name-of-uiview-that-was-touched).

Comment: so it's gonna print "view", isn't it?

Comment: i mean its output will always be the same. "view" and nothing else

Comment: you don't understand. the questioner wants to find out what variable exactly has been passed to the method. but since you print it INSIDE the method the name of the variable will always be "view" which is not what the questioner needs

Comment: Yeah, I got your point now. I don't think it's possible thing to do without doing anything else.